# Graphing Vortex

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am trying to graph the shape of a vortex that I have created in a spinning trough. 
The graph has both maximum and minimum x values 
The area under the graph ( between these max and min values ) remains constant, but the  line is changeable.

Comment: Are you asking something like: "Suppose you have a centrifuge attached to a thin upright rectangular vessel containing an amount of fluid. As you spin the centrifuge at various speeds, the shape of the fluid accumulates on the outer end of the vessel. What functional curve describes the contour of the fluid's surface at various speeds?"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the curve is a parabola $f(x)=p\,x^2+q$,
consider a right half of the profile.

The area under the curve is derived as

\begin{align} 
S(p,q)&=\int_0^a f(x)dx=
\tfrac13\,p\,a^3+q\,a
.
\end{align}

Let $S(p,q)=\sigma$. then, using $q$ as a control parameter
(the height of the vortex eye),
we have

\begin{align} 
p(q)&=3\frac{\sigma-q\,a}{a^3}
.
\end{align}

Here is an example for $S=20\times5=100$:

[image]